# Arduino Nano in PCB for a controlled heating rig - Can't get it to work

Tags: arduino, mosfet, pcb-design, routing

**Background**

I'm making a heat sealing machine. The mechanical side is all OK but the electronics is challenging me. Here's the gist of the setup. I've put it all in the image below. Apologies for the rather unconventional circuit diagram...
[image]

**The Target**

I need to make a PCB that has all the components together with the Arduino Nano - everything soldered on one board -- so that I can install it in my machine.

**What works so far**

I have built the circuit on a breadboard. It works great, so the circuit itself and the Arduino code is functional (as is the PID algorithm).

**The problem**

After testing on a breadboard, naturally the next step is to translate it to a PCB.

Using Altium CircuitMaker, I have made the circuit and routed it as in the image below.
Here is the schematic
[image: Circuit schematic design]

and here is the routed PCB.
[image: PCB Routing]

After transferring, etching and soldering, I have found that the circuit does not work. It actually burnt the regulator on my Nano and fried it but I am unable to tell why this is happening. This is even before I attach the external 15V supply for the higher power part of the circuit. It literally burns out even when I put the 9V into Vin.

I'm using a single-sided copper clad board for my PCB so I am limited to a single conductive surface. My transfer mechanism is also rather coarse, so I'm sticking with 70mil pads and 40mil traces.

Here are some images of the final board
[image: Final soldered board]

And here's the solder side of the PCB
[image]

**Where I'd like some help**

I'd like to learn what's wrong with my board routing, and anything else that I'm doing wrong from a circuit-making perspective, that's preventing my circuit from operating correctly.

I'm a little stumped because I have routed everything as in the breadboard version of the circuit, but it doesn't work. I suspect there is something seriously wrong with how I've routed the board, but I have no idea what it could be. I just don't have the knowledge.

Happy to share the CircuitMaker files and Arduino code if necessary.

Comment: I think we'll need the proper circuit schematic to compare with your PCB routing.

Comment: Along with a schematic, a photos of the finished product, with components installed, would help find misplaced parts.

Comment: Installing the MOSFET backwards and connecting to the 12 V supply could be a problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have added in the schematic and some images of the final board.

Comment: Your photos show the MOSFETs connected correctly and your design pinout matches the datasheet.

Comment: Can you add a photo of the solder side? Was 9V the correct polarity?

Comment: Measure between the +5 and ground with a multimeter (red probe on +5) on the lowest resistance range and see what you get (with no power applied, of course). If it shows a short find out where that is. It could be incomplete etching, a solder short or (less likely) within the temperature module.

Comment: Thank you for the comments - I have attached an image of the solder side. I can also confirm the correct polarity of the 9V supply.

Comment: I notice that HEATER + and HEATER - seem to be swapped in your CircuitMaker diagram, though it may not matter for the final circuit. As a nitpick, I would avoid labeling the 9 V positive and negative terminals as +9 V and -9 V, because those labels imply that one terminal is 9 V higher than ground and the other is 9 V lower than ground, for a total voltage of 18 V. Some alternatives would be to label them as +9 V and 0 V, or as 9 V (+) and 9 V (-).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like your etching is incomplete and it has left some 'whiskers' between traces. There may be more (I think I see the 9V too, but maybe the input power has burned that out):

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing that out. I actually only noticed that after looking at the high resolution photo myself just now. I will physically remove those whiskers and report back

Comment: If you get a strong light behind the PCB and a magnifier you will be able to see copper whiskers more easily- it will help differentiate between copper and reflections from flux etc.. Just to the left of the circle above also looks like a short. And the bottom two of the RH pins. I'm sure you've heard this before, but a superior 2-sided PCB from a Chinese factory is very inexpensive and will give you a lot of advantages  (such as 100% testing, solder mask and solvent-resistant designator printing).

Comment: Remembering the first few times I etched a PCB, it's worth checking the resistance between solder joints that should be near infinite. If they are only a couple hundred Ohm, your PCB isn't as good as you want it to be. The tracks indicated in this answer sure look suspicious, I'd start measuring between them.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have investigated and yes you are right, the whiskers are the problem! Thank you !!